# Tool for java code coverage on GitHub

Tags: java, testing, github, junit, travis-ci

I have a Java project created in IntelliJ and using Gradle.

My repository is hosted on GitHub, I've also integrated Travis CI.

My tests are done using JUnit and Mockito, Java 8.

I'm looking for a tool that would automatically run tests whenever I push to my repository, providing me with information if tests passed and code coverage information. Would like it to generate a GitHub badge just like Travis CI does, so that I can see how each branch is covered and if it's passing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I decided to go with [Codecov](https://codecov.io/)

[Here's](https://github.com/capybaracreations/TDDAndDesignPatternsExample) my GitHub repo with example implementation.

Answer (score 4):

I use [JaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco) to capture coverage statistics which get published to [Coveralls](https://coveralls.io/) to track coverage changes between builds and visualize the results. Coveralls also provides a badge with a coverage percentage.

Gradle/Travis/Github examples [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-maven-share) and [here](https://github.com/uklance/tiny-ioc)

Answer (score 0):

With https://codecov.io/, the official example here is more up to date compared to the best answer: 
https://github.com/codecov/example-gradle

However, I the CodeCov badge is set up in a nice way in the best answer's code, compared to the official examples which seem to have no badge in the README.

EDIT: After trying to set up all of this, I really disrecommend using CodeCov for private repos (although it can work well for public repos). Full of bugs. Very mad.