# How to upload test reports of Kotlin sources to Coveralls?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, jacoco, coveralls, gradle-kotlin-dsl

> I want to upload my Jacoco test report to Coveralls automatically after my Travis build finishes. It works for Java, but how to configure it for Kotlin?

**Error message**

I can generate a Jacoco test report locally and on Travis, but when Travis tries to submit to coveralls it fails with message

```
> Task :coveralls
No source file found on the project: "kotlin-template-project"
With coverage file: /home/travis/build/myname/myreponame/build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
```

Google links me to the Gradle plugin [implementation](https://github.com/kt3k/coveralls-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/kt3k/gradle/plugin/coveralls/CoverallsTask.groovy) which shows where it throws this message, which tells me (I think) that the Jacoco report file is found but not the source files which coveralls apparently needs.

**What I tried**

Hence, I tried pointing the coveralls task to my source files, in all of these ways:

```
coveralls {
    sourceDirs += allprojects.sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs.flatten()
    sourceDirs += files(sourceSets.main.kotlin.srcDirs).files.absolutePath
    project.extensions.coveralls.sourceDirs += project.sourceSets.main.kotlin.srcDirs
    sourceDirs += ['src/main/kotlin']
    jacocoReportPath = 'build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml'
    sourceDirs += ['src/test/kotlin']
    sourceDirs += ["${projectDir}/src/main/kotlin"]
}
```

I also tried adding `sourceSets project.sourceSets.main` to the `jacocoTestReport` task.

**Project setup**

My minimal `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {

    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.2.50'
    id 'java' // Required by at least JUnit.

    // Test coverage
    id 'jacoco'

    // Upload jacoco coverage reports to coveralls
    id 'com.github.kt3k.coveralls'  version '2.8.2'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'

    // JUnit 5
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.2.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.2.0'
    testRuntime 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-console:1.2.0'

    // Kotlintest
    testCompile 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest-core:3.1.6'
    testCompile 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest-assertions:3.1.6'
    testCompile 'io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:3.1.6'

    // Spek
    testCompile 'org.jetbrains.spek:spek-api:1.1.5'
    testRuntime 'org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:1.1.5'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}

test {
    // Enable JUnit 5 (Gradle 4.6+).
    useJUnitPlatform()

    // Always run tests, even when nothing changed.
    dependsOn 'cleanTest'

    // Show test results.
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}

// Test coverage reporting
jacocoTestReport {
    // Enable xml for coveralls.
    reports {
        html.enabled = true
        xml.enabled = true
        xml.setDestination(file("${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml"))
    }
}

coveralls {
    sourceDirs += ['src/main/kotlin']
    jacocoReportPath = 'build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml'
}
```

**Related issues**

- Essentially the same issue is on https://github.com/kt3k/coveralls-gradle-plugin/issues/32 but the solution is to set `sourceDirs` and `jacocoReportPath` which I already have tried.
- At https://github.com/kt3k/coveralls-gradle-plugin/issues/39 and https://github.com/kt3k/coveralls-gradle-plugin/issues/63 it is suggested to add `sourceDirs += ['src/main/kotlin']` which sounds sensible but doesn't help. Same for, from the first link, `sourceDirs = files(sourceSets.main.kotlin.srcDirs).files.absolutePath`.
- From https://github.com/kt3k/coveralls-gradle-plugin/issues/77 the solution is `project.extensions.coveralls.sourceDirs += project.sourceSets.main.kotlin.srcDirs` which I tried.
- The question [Kotlin code coverage in CI pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47470492/kotlin-code-coverage-in-ci-pipeline) is phrased rather generally, but a comment points to [discuss.kotlinlang.org](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/gradle-code-coverage-report/390) where someone shows a way to improve the Jacoco result regarding kotlin, and the answer links to the Jacoco Gradle plugin which I use and works: when I run the `jacocoTestReport` task a report is generated in `build/reports/jacoco/test/`, both in xml and html.
- The question [Kotlin Test Coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48220460/kotlin-test-coverage) is also phrased general and answered with an unnecessarily complex build file from which I learned nothing new.
- The question [Measure test coverage for Kotlin code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48554157/measure-test-coverage-for-kotlin-code) claims that the Jacoco report does not work, but for me this is not the case as I said.
- There are similar questions for Java, like [Tool for java code coverage on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38867350/tool-for-java-code-coverage-on-github) but for me when I use Java it all works fine.

PS Actually I want to use the Gradle Kotlin DSL, but since nobody seems to use it I'm asking this question for Gradle. But in the end I want this question solved for the Kotlin DSL as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar experience with a variety of QA products not supporting or only partially supporting Kotlin codebases. Tried submitting support PRs to a couple of  projects to no avail.

In the end ended up going with Coveralls and contributed a Kotlin focused plugin for the [platform](https://docs.coveralls.io/kotlin)

https://github.com/nbaztec/coveralls-jacoco-gradle-plugin

### Usage

Include the plugin in your `build.gradle.kts` (similar for `build.gradle` files):

```
plugins {
    jacoco
    id("com.github.nbaztec.coveralls-jacoco")
}
```

Then set the environment variable `COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN` to the token from your Coveralls page.

Now you can use the `coverallsJacoco` task to publish a coverage report.

For more information and usage in CI, see
https://github.com/nbaztec/coveralls-jacoco-gradle-plugin

Comment: After I tried to use this plugin to submit the unitTest report I generated for my Kotlin project, I experienced some issues. More concretely I didn't manage to provide a correct path to my Kotlin source code sets on `reportSourceSets` after trying many different options. And if I leave this field blank i.e. "", the compiler will complain with a `ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.io.File` Do you have an example on how to provide this path correctly @nbaztec ?

Comment: it's supposed to be a `Collection<File>` so `[file("src/main/java"), ...]` / `listOf(file("src/main/kotlin"), ...)` should be used

[docs](https://github.com/nbaztec/coveralls-jacoco-gradle-plugin#multi-project-support---android) might help, I'll perhaps add more examples on option usage

Answer (score 4):

[edit August 2020] @nbaztec wrote a plugin to support Kotlin, please see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63337867/4126843).

---

**Old answer:**

Kotlin is not supported by Coveralls, see for example this open isse that was mentioned in the question as well (in the question it was also mentioned that the workaround presented there does not work): https://github.com/kt3k/coveralls-gradle-plugin/issues/77

Solution: try [Codecov.io](https://codecov.io/) instead.
Install it to GitHub using the [Marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace/codecov) and add to your `.travis.yml`

```
after_success:
  - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

Then commit and push, done!

You can view the result (after the build finished) at https://codecov.io/gh/githubaccountname/reponame

Comment: Was in the same boat running from coverage to coverage yet no luck with Kotlin. Ended up contributing to coveralls with a Kotlin focused plugin:

https://docs.coveralls.io/kotlin

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but in case anyone else is struggling with nbaztec like me, I want to give an alternative that worked for me: https://github.com/kt3k/coveralls-gradle-plugin

And besides what is in README.md, I needed this detail in build.gradle:

```
coveralls {
    sourceDirs += ['src/main/kotlin']
    jacocoReportPath "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/report.xml"
}
```

Comment: Interesting, as the question indicates that using this plugin like that did not work. But maybe it has been updated and it works now. Thanks for the answer, in any case.